# bigQuery - Join

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join two databases on the ID. The first database on price quotes does not have the data on websites, so I want to join it in from the logs database. However, in the logs database the ID is not unique, but the first chronological appearance of the ID - this is the right website.
When I run the query below, I get:

> Resources exceeded during query execution.

Hence I don't know whether the problem is the code or something else.

Thanks

```
SELECT ID, user,busWeek, count(*) as num FROM [datastore.quotes] 

Join (
select objectID, first(website) from (
select objectID, website, date from [datastore.allLogs] 
order by date) group by objectID)
as Logs

on ID = objectID

group by ID,user,busWeek
```

Comment: Could you push your double-select in another temporary table, and then do a join on that? While that will be two queries, the fact the first part won't have to be ran at the same time as the outer select might help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
SELECT ID, user,busWeek, count(*) as num FROM [datastore.quotes] 

Join EACH (
select objectID, first(website) from (
select objectID, website, date from [datastore.allLogs] 
order by date) group EACH by objectID)
as Logs

on ID = objectID

group by ID,user,busWeek
```

Note the 'EACH' - that keyword won't be needed in the future, but it's still useful today.

Comment: It's weird since the query returns the same "Resources exceeded during query execution." It returns it even if I limit the query by 50

Comment: The limit doesn't change how your query runs. It just changes what is returned. If there are not enough resources to do the query, the limit won't help, because the limit is applied after the query fully ran. Can you put your joined table in an actual table and do a join each there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in ORDER BY. This brings all calculation to one node which causes "Resources Exceeded" message. I understand you need it to bring first (by date) website for each object.
Try to rewrite this select (inside join) to be partitioned.
For example using window functions with OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY)
In this case, I think, you have chance to make this in parallel

See below for reference
[Window Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions)